# hive specific alias not working

Tags: hive

I tried running the same hive queries with different alias but there is something which I am unable to understand. The queries with alias name "first" and "second" is giving an error and the same query with any other alias is working fine. I am attaching the screen shot of both the queries with this message. Can someone explain why this is happening.

[Query 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DVNXH.png)

[Query 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fjlBy.png)

Answer (score 0):

**first** and **second** are reserved keywords in hive. It is a good practice to avoid these, but in case you need to use them, you have to use a **`**

In your case, below query should work:

```
select first.id, first.name, second.id, second.zip
from personname `first`
join personzip `second`
on first.id = second.id;
```